# Hibernate, replace null value in hql

Tags: java, hibernate, null, hql

How can I replace (or get result with null value) null value in HQL? In my case the `SomeObject` can be null. I have relation Many-To-One between `Clazz` and `SomeObject`:

```
SELECT c.name, c.someObject.name from Clazz c
```

I've tried:

```
SELECT c.name, coalesce(c.someObject.name, ' ') from Clazz c
```

but it doesn't return any row.

Comment: 'many'-side is `Clazz`, 'one'-side is `SomeObject` and it's value can be null

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may want to note that there is no such thing as a 'many-to-null' relation. If the referenced object (`SomeObject`) is `null` when persisting a `Clazz` entity *no* entry will be made into the `SomeObject` database table.

Then, when you try to access the (non-existent) `SomeObject` in your query (`c.someObject.name`) Hibernate will implicitly build an *inner* join, which of course will exclude the `Clazz` object in question because the join cannot be fulfilled.

Try to explicitly use an [outer join](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/queryhql.html#queryhql-joins); this will solve your problem.

By the way: You can let hibernate [output](http://www.javalobby.org/java/forums/t44119.html) the SQL statements it generates, which allows to better understand why a given query behaves in a certain way.

Answer (score 0):

`c.someObject.name` is an implicit inner join between Clazz and SomeObject. So, since it's an inner join, it automatically filters out Clazz instances having a `null` someObject.

You need an outer join:

```
select c.name, s.name from Clazz c
left join c.someObject s
```